# host https website using IIS across local area network

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, lan

I have a website hosted on IIS which can accessed across the Local Area Network by using the IP address of the Server computer. But I can only access the website on client computers using http, when I use https I get security alert on the browsers as shown in the image below,

[image]

I even got a self signed certificate on the server computer and in the server computer I can use https without any security alert but I can't do the same on client computers on LAN. Is it possible to achieve that? If so please let me know. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: “I get security alert on the browsers.” The security alert is important, as it can tell you what might be wrong.

Comment: @LexLi Alert as in it asks for certificates

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0 Don't make a statement using your own words. Show the exact alert message or paste a screenshot as part of the question.

Comment: @LexLi ok added a screenshot

Comment: The error message is quite clear, that the machine with the browser opened did not trust the self-signed certificate. You either make that machine trust it (by installing it to that machine), or switch to a true certificate that is trusted everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your certificate is not trusted by other computers, because they don't recognize you as a trusted authority, the solution is easy, even if you ask google it will respond with steps to do this (for chrome in this example):

> Go to Chrome Settings. 
>   Click on "advanced settings" 
>   Under HTTPS/SSL click to "Manage Certificates" 
>   Go to "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" 
>   Click to "Import" 
>   There will be a pop-up window that will ask you if you want to install this certificate. Click "yes".

Better idea maybe, instead of making them trust your self-signed certificate would be to generate a certificate by some verified authority.

I have recently generated a free certificate by the https://letsencrypt.org/ portal (and no, I do not have any interest in promoting it) except it's free and it simply works fine.

Comment: My experience with letsencrypt (and I don't have neither interest nor relation with them too) is the same. Better that I could imagine.